# VBA Macro to enter range of data from excel to website then submit form

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty new to VBA and Macros and currently trying to use VBA to gather numbers from a range of cells in a worksheet. Then put them into a form on a website and submit the form.

This is what I have so far. I'm not sure why the range won't populate the text box on the website. (http://www.centraltransportint.com/confirm/trace.aspx) If I set the range to just A2 it will put that cell's value into the textbox but won't put anymore than just the one cell.

My goal after getting the form to submit is to then copy a portion of the results from the website to be displayed in column B in Excel. I found where the information I need is stored in the next page after submitting the form so I'm feeling pretty confident I can handle that.

However, I can not seem to get a range of cells to populate the text box.

The line (IE.Document.all("_ctl0:lstType").Value = "PuN") is used to switch the drop down menu from pro number to pickup number.

```
Sub GetHTMLDocument()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "http://www.centraltransportint.com/confirm/trace.aspx"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

IE.Document.all("_ctl0:lstType").Value = "PuN"
IE.Document.all("_ctl0:traceNumbers").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("pickups").Range("a2:a20")

IE.Document.all("_ctl0:traceSubmit").Click

End Sub
```

Submit button code

```
<input name="_ctl0:traceSubmit" id="_ctl0_traceSubmit" language="javascript" onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("_ctl0:traceSubmit", "", true, "", "", false, false))' type="image" src="../images/btn_traceship.gif" border="0">
```

Edit: Okay it's not accepting my pickup number because it says that it doesn't include the dashes even though the macro puts the number in with the dashes(example, Cell A2 contains: PU-946-110109442013). If i manually copy and paste it into the text box it searches. But if my macro puts it in the text box it ignores the dashes.

The website pulls up "The Pickup Number must be entered in the correct format. 
For example, search for PU-xxx-xxxxxxx instead of searching for PUxxxxxxxxxx. If you do not include the dashes, you will not see the status information for your shipment. "

Comment: Are there more than 1 pickup numbers in the range, if so do the values need to be separated by a specific character?  Is there any white space at the end or beginning?

Comment: Yes, I have 5 pickup numbers in a2:a7. There are no spaces in front or behind them on excel. I think they need to be below each other in the text box so, I'm thinking they might need to be separated by an enter. As I copy them into the text box from excel, each one is on it's own line.